# Get the parent process doesnt work in Mavericks

Tags: macos, shell, unix, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to get the parent process of the process, which launched them.

```
ps -o ppid -p $PID
```

it returns the root pid `1` rather than the process id.

Any idea, why does that happens?

Comment: What do you get if you do `ps -ef | grep $PID`? In the 3rd column you have the PPID. Maybe the parent died and now it hangs from the main process 1.

Comment: No parent isn't died. Its safari, its still active.

Comment: But what do you get if you perform that `ps -ef | grep $PID` I mentioned before? Also `1`?

Comment: I get only `1`. No other process, like :`1216003782  5713     1   0  4:52PM ??         0:00.07 com.apple.automator.xpc.workflowServiceRunner`

Comment: But the process supposed to be `Safari`

Comment: Probably Safari is the grandparent. Safari launched something and that something launched this processes with pid $PID. And somehow, the intermediate process died.

Comment: I tried even this `ps -oppid $PID`. Again I'm getting only `1`. Actually Safari starts the "Automator service". So Safari should its parent right? Or I'm wrong here?

Comment: When it is launched, yes. Once the parent died, the parent info gets removed, the process becomes orphan and the parent id is set to `1`. So you can know the grand parent id by going up in the tre... just when the parent is still alive.

Comment: @fedorqui How do you explain that in Activity Monitor.app and using the hierarchy view. The children processes are listed under Safari but ppid returns 1 when run on them instead of Safari's pid.

Comment: @markhunte I would have to see it to really understand. Could you share a screenshot or some text in pastebin? I am mentioning the default behaviour, but maybe in OS X things work a bit differently...

Comment: will do when I am back in my Maverick machine later today

Comment: Also here is a thread that is related http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145074/how-do-i-determine-which-application-launched-automator-service/145183#comment171586_145183  - Note the answer given is where it was discovered that although it works in Snow Leopard it does not in Mavericks